# Java OutputStream only flushes data on close

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.178.47", 82);

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write("{ \"phone\": \"23456789\" }".getBytes());
out.flush();
```

//Server

```
InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int i = 0;
while((i = in.read()) >= 0) {
    bOut.write(i);
}

String complete = new String(bOut.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

I had tried to send data via OutputStream to a socket but the data is not flushing. If I add an `out.close();` to the end then it works perfectly, but the socket is closed and I cannot accept the response. Does anybody know why? The server is not giving any type of error. I had used Java 1.7!

Comment: What does the server code look like?

Comment: How did you confirm that the output is not sent?

Comment: Well, you know, an `OutputStream` has `.flush()`. Also, the way your write your JSON is broken: it uses the JRE's default encoding. Why don't you use a JSON library instead?

Comment: A socket `OutputStream` doesn't flush at all. `flush()` does nothing, whenever you call it. The problem is that you are reading until EOS but the sender is never closing the stream.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that the server is waiting for the end of line. If this is the case add "\n" to the text

Comment: This was the exact thing my program was doing.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the labelling "//Server" in your question, but I'm assuming the following code is the server code:

```
InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int i = 0;
while((i = in.read()) >= 0) {
    bOut.write(i);
}

String complete = new String(bOut.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

This will continue to read, blocking each time, until it gets a value from `read()` less than zero.  That only happens if the stream is closed.

It really looks like you need to establish your own protocol.  So instead of looking for "<=0" look for some constant value that signals the end of the message.

Here's a quick demonstration of what I mean (I didn't have time yesterday).  I have 3 classes, `Message`,`MyClient` (which also is the `main` class), and `MyServer`.  Notice there isn't anything about sending or receiving a newline.  Nothing is setting tcpNoDelay.  But it works fine.  Some other notes:

- This code only sends and receives a single request and response.
- It doesn't support sending multiple `Message` instances.  That would require checking for the start of a `Message` as well as the end.

`Message` class:

```
public class Message {
    public static final String MSG_START = "<message>";
    public static final String MSG_END = "</message>";

    private final String content;

    public Message(String string){
        content = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return MSG_START + content + MSG_END;
    }
}
```

`MyServer` class

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{
    public static final int PORT = 55555;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            String message = getMessage(socket);
            System.out.println("Server got the message:  " + message);
            sendResponse(socket);
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private void sendResponse(Socket socket) throws IOException{
        Message message = new Message("Ack");
        System.out.println("Server now sending a response to the client: " + message);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(message.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    private String getMessage(Socket socket) throws IOException{

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024<<8];
        while(sb.lastIndexOf(Message.MSG_END) == -1){
            int bytesRead = in.read(bytes);
            sb.append(new String(bytes,0,bytesRead,"UTF-8"));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

`MyClient` class

```
public class MyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyClient client = new MyClient();

        Thread server = new Thread(new MyServer());
        server.start();

        client.performCall();
    }

    public void performCall(){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",MyServer.PORT);
            sendMessage(socket, "Why hello there!");
            System.out.println("Client got a response from the server: " + getResponse(socket));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getResponse(Socket socket) throws IOException{
        String response;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while(sb.lastIndexOf(Message.MSG_END) == -1){
            int bytesRead = in.read(bytes);
            sb.append(new String(bytes,0,bytesRead,"UTF-8"));
        }
        response = sb.toString();

        return response;
    }

    public void sendMessage(Socket socket, String message) throws IOException{
        Message msg = new Message(message);
        System.out.println("Client now sending message to server: " + msg);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(msg.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

The output

```
Client now sending message to server: Why hello there!
Server got the message:  Why hello there!
Server now sending a response to the client: Ack
Client got a response from the server: Ack

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It's not possible to send -1 from the client code. He is reading in single bytes. As long as the connection hasn't been closed he can only receive values between 0 and 255. If the client called `out.write(-1)` the server would receive 255.

Comment: @SpiderPig To be honest, I wasn't really sure.  I have vague recollections of doing that in the past, but I'm probably remembering it wrong.  What you said makes sense.  I'm updating my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you are not flushing properly, but that the reading code waits for the socket to disconnect before handling the data:

`while((i = in.read()) >= 0)`

Will loop as long as something can be read from `in` (the socket's InputStream). The condition will not fail until the other peer disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

There is buffering that occurs for performance reasons (read up on Nagle's algorithm).

Comment: Great minds :)  I tried to post before you but this site started going really slow (other sites were fine).

Comment: This will have exactly no effect on this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code it seems ok.  However you are sending less than the MTU Nagle's algothrim could be holding it back until enough data is present for a full packet or you close the socket.

So - try this:

```
socket.setTCPNoDelay(true);
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTcpNoDelay-boolean-

Comment: Also try padding out your string to > 1500 bytes.  That would prove it.

Comment: This will have exactly no effect on this problem.